# Google Maps API. calling multiple info windows from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have searched all over this site to find an answer with no luck. I have an array of lat, and lng markers and I'd like to open an info window based on the array index. I got it to work by replacing markers with variables instead of an array list, but I want to keep my code DRY. Here is my code:

```
function initMap() {
    var locations = [
        ["blairCountyPA", 40.453132, -78.384223],
        ["scrantonPA", 41.408969, -75.662412],
        ["warringtonTownshipPA", 40.250319, -75.166212],
        ["lancasterCountyPA", 40.046657, -76.178374],
        ["berkeleyCountyWV", 39.488560, -78.065193],
        ["bowieMD", 39.006777, -76.779136],
        ["anneArundelCountyMD", 38.953011, -76.548823],
        ["shenandoahVA", 38.483457, -78.849748],
        ["calvertCountyMD", 38.494950, -76.502574],
        ["salsiburyMD", 38.360674, -75.599369],
        ["berlinMD", 38.322615, -75.217689],
        ["ocMD", 38.336503, -75.084906],
        ["lynchburgVA", 37.413754, -79.142246]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.488560, -78.065193)
    }); 

    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            icon: 'images/pin-cloud.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map    
        });
    }

    var blairCountyContentString = 
    '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Blair County, PA</h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    "<p>insert info here</p>" +
    '<p><b>Resources</b>: <a href="https://efc.umd.edu/assets/sw_case_studies/blair_county_final.pdf" <span>Case Study Blair County, PA</span> </a></p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';

    var blairCountyInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: blairCountyContentString,
        position: locations[0]
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        blairCountyInfowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

My issue seems to be with the "position: locations[0]" object literal. Sometimes I get an error stating that this needs to be a number value of lng, lat...Tried it though with no luck. The window currently opens but only for the last index of the array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See updated Code. Now customize the infowindow content

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/o9dvcmfs/3/)

```
function initMap() {
  var marker = [];
  var locations = [
    ["blairCountyPA", 40.453132, -78.384223],
    ["scrantonPA", 41.408969, -75.662412],
    ["warringtonTownshipPA", 40.250319, -75.166212],
    ["lancasterCountyPA", 40.046657, -76.178374],
    ["berkeleyCountyWV", 39.488560, -78.065193],
    ["bowieMD", 39.006777, -76.779136],
    ["anneArundelCountyMD", 38.953011, -76.548823],
    ["shenandoahVA", 38.483457, -78.849748],
    ["calvertCountyMD", 38.494950, -76.502574],
    ["salsiburyMD", 38.360674, -75.599369],
    ["berlinMD", 38.322615, -75.217689],
    ["ocMD", 38.336503, -75.084906],
    ["lynchburgVA", 37.413754, -79.142246]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.488560, -78.065193)
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      var ContentString =
        '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + locations[i][0] + '</h1>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        "<p>insert info here</p>" +
        '<p><b>Resources</b>: <a href="https://efc.umd.edu/assets/sw_case_studies/blair_county_final.pdf" <span>Case Study ' + locations[i][0] + '</span> </a></p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(ContentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not working for me and it's not working right in the fiddle because the second pin from the top is Blair County. Not the last pin... Why would I have to remove the "blairCountyPA" in the array? That's how I know which pin it is. I couldn't select from that array? Hm, maybe I'm thinking about this incorrectly. I think it's something to do with the way my array is set up because I don't know how it's being indexed when I have nested arrays.

Comment: Nice dude! That's much appreciated. Up vote for you.